# $find() returns null in IE 9

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-9

Sometimes the `$find()` method which is in `Sys.Application.add_load` returns `null`, could someone please help me with this.

Please note that

- This is an **IE 9** specific issue
- Happens occasionally
- Method `$('#id')` returns the correct jQuery object
- Element that I'm trying to find is a `SPAN` inside `RadDockZone`
- And the same `$find()` function returns AJAX component after the page is loaded

Code

```
Sys.Application.add_load(gridRefresh_ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking);

function gridRefresh_ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking() {
    var gridctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking = $find('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking');
    Sys.Application.remove_load(gridRefresh_ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking);
    if(gridctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking._customData['RefreshOnPageLoad']) 
    gridctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking.refresh();
}
```

Comment: what did you tried? Write your code please.

Comment: This question asks for an example, otherwise how are we supposed to know what's happening and why?

Comment: `$find()` returns an ASP.NET AJAX component, not an element. If you want an element, use `$get()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I need the corresponding AJAX component.

Comment: @user, we'll need more information to have a chance to determine what's going on. Does the problem happen only during partial postbacks, or are full postbacks impacted? Do you have specific initialization in the grid component that could delay the creation of other components until after its `initialize()` method has returned?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - Further digging shows that on the occasions when this happens ‘Sys.Application.add_init’ delegates get executed after the ‘Sys.Application.add_load’ delegates. I think somehow creation of the components get delayed.

Comment: @Ramesh, then try scheduling your `GridBooking()` function with `add_init()` instead of `add_load()`. This might get rid of the race condition.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi - Sorry about the late reply, but I was busy with some priority issue. It didn't work, the component that I'm looking for in my function gets created in an another init delegate which gets executed after mine (this is same when I add mine as both init and load delegates), also I tried by adding mine as a PageRequestManager's pageLoaded delegate. Could you suggest a way to avoid this race condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you're using the syntax properly. See this as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/turiyag/7wntu/

```
$("#content").find("#someid").css({border:"5px solid blue"});
```

Comment: This returns jQuery object, but I need AJAX component.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work:

```
var xyz = $find('ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking');
```

The method get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element:

```
var xyz = $('parentSelector').find('descendantsSelector');
```

In case it is an ID you use as 'descendantsSelector', you don't need find at all, ID has to be unique, so it should just be:

```
var xyz = $('#ctl00_contentPlaceHolder_ctl02_2_C_ctl00_GridBooking');
```

Comment: You're confusing `$find()` (ASP.NET AJAX) with `$.fn.find()` (jQuery). These are two different beasts entirely.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ah, I see, misunderstood the question.